# Disable/enable a tab on Android depending on condition

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a `Tabhost Activity` with 3 child Activities `Tab1 Tab2 and Tab3`, i want to disable one of the 3 tabs if a `condition` is true, if not it should be enabled. this is how proceeded :

```
//tab is my TabHost,
tab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             // Only logged users may have access to my Tab 3
            if (v==tab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2))
            {
                if(!LoginManager.getInstance().isLoggedIn())
                    tab.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(false);
                    else
                tab.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(true);
            }

        }
    });
```

Apparently my approach is not right, that's why i need you, to help me solve this problem.

Comment: "I have a Tabhost Activity with 3 child Activities Tab1 Tab2 and Tab3" -- this approach has been deprecated for **years**.

Comment: I know about that, but I'm not sure why your repeating me?

Comment: "I know about that" -- then why are you still using child activities? Programmers have long since moved onto better-supported techniques (`FragmentTabHost`, `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, action bar tabs, etc). "I'm not sure why your repeating me?" -- I quoted the specific passage from your question that represents the deprecated behavior.

Comment: If i use `FragmentTabHost` is that going to solve my problem?

Comment: Since I am not aware of any tab solution for Android that offers disabled tabs, eventually you will wind up coming up with another solution or writing your own tab implementation.

Comment: All I want is to prevent unlogged users from accessing some Tabs, perhaps there are other solutions to this problem, with no need to disable tabs?

Comment: You can disable the contents of the tabs. Or, you can not add the tabs until after they log in.